# How to share my cli information (variable, etc) to child process which is a bash shell script

Tags: c++, c, linux, bash, shell

I have a command-line interface (let's say mycli) which has its own properties (env variable, etc). mycli have a command which invokes a shell script (child process) which in turn invokes a c/cpp executable which wants to use variables/properties from mycli.

Is there any way to pass such information in shell scripts which could be used by the invoked executable?

Already browsed a lot but no luck.

Comment: When you invoke the shell script child process, set up the environment variables to be used by the child process.

Comment: Environment variables are inherited by child processes created by [`fork`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html).

Comment: ... which includes those launched by a shell.

Comment: Why do you execute a script (shell script) that executes an executable? Why don't you call directly the executable? How does the executable called by the script receive the values!?

Comment: A way to pass values to the shell script might be to call it passing all values on the shell command line something such: system("script.sh a b c d e f") ... but maybe is to broad.

Comment: My requirement is such that the script has to invoke the executable.

Answer (score 1):

Simple `export` of your variables should do the job e.g.:

`export MY_VAR=my_value`

Exported variables are available for all subshells i.e. subshell spawned by your current shell, the subsequent shell spawned but the subshell and so on.

Everything that is available in your current environment as `environment variable` ( which you can display it using `env` command ) is already exported and available for all subshells. Notice that any variable you have defined and exported is also on the list.